# storageReference.getDownloadUrl() is returning null for audio file stored in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to get the download url of a mp3 file stored in Firebase Storage.
The path of the storage on firebase is "Categories/numbers/one.mp3".
Below is the code I am using to get the download Url but seems like it is not working. I am getting the downloadUrl as null.

Could somebody please help?

Code:

```
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Categories").child(mCategory).child("one.mp3");
            storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(uri.toString());
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: please update your question with stacktrace

Comment: You can store Your mp3 files records in database and then simply retrieve data model object and get url.?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this

```
storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                try {
                      @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUrl = 
                         taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                        uploadImageUrl = downloadUrl.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "url to your file..."+uploadImageUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //rest your code
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please explain why do we need to use UploadTask.TaskSnapshot?

Comment: @VarunAM look to get the download Url i used UploadTask.TaskSnapshot which has a inbuild method that gets the url of any file on firebase storage:--     Uri 
getDownloadUrl()
Returns a long lived download URL with a revokable token.

Comment: also check this url https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask.TaskSnapshot

Comment: @VarunAM happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Hope so this may work.!

```
storageRef.child("Categories").child(mCategory).child("one.mp3").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(uri.toString());
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

}
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
}
});
// Alternative way
storageRef.child("Categories").child(mCategory).child("one.mp3").getDownloadUrl().getResult();


 StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
```

Comment: Kindly upload Firebase Storage Picture.!

Comment: @VarunAM there is one thing more you can do ..? add a child in node having Url in it and store it in firebase database and then fetch that node you will get your Result.?